# how to remove the Maximize icon from form and leave the minimize

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I want to disable maximizing my form so I set MaxmimizeBox to false and lest MinimizeBox true the problem is that it shows the maximize icon- it is grayed out but yet shown. when setting both maximize and minimize to false it does not show the icons at all. how can I show the minimize icon and not the maximize one?

Comment: Show it disabled and be consistent with every other program that can be minimized but not maximized.

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible: you'll have to implement your own frame and window artifacts if you really want to hide it.